# How to add a "mobile data ON/OFF" shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

This is one feature I have to toggle frequently and there doesn't seem to be a shortcut for this. By default it is a 3 step click : `Settings -> Mobile -> Mobile Data`.

Is there a way to add a shortcut for this ?

The web site [brdrck.me/settings/wifi](http://brdrck.me/settings/wifi) used to give custom shortcuts, but not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Without a jailbreak, that's not possible.